# rational function and rational values

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics, polynomials

Let $f$ be a rational function with real coefficients, i.e. $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}(x)$.

Show that if $f(r)\in \mathbb{Q}$ for infinitely many $r\in \mathbb{Q}$, then $f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}(x)$.

---

Could you help me with this problem ?

I don't know how to solve it.

(I know that if $f$ were a polynomial, the problem would be easy.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires a little knowledge of vector spaces.

We write $f(x) = F(x) / G(x)$ with $F, G \in \Bbb R[x]$.

Let $S$ be the sub-$\Bbb Q$-vector space of $\Bbb R$ generated by the coefficients of $F$ and $G$. Clearly, $S$ is finite dimensional over $\Bbb Q$.

We take a $\Bbb Q$-basis of $S$, say $\{s_1, \dots, s_n\}$.

It is then possible to write $F(x) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^ns_i \cdot U_i(x)$ and $G(x) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^ns_i \cdot V_i(x)$ with $U_i, V_i \in \Bbb Q[x]$.

Now for each pair of indices $i, j$, we look at the polynomial $D_{ij} = U_iV_j - V_iU_j \in \Bbb Q[x]$. I claim that $D_{ij}$ is the zero polynomial.

> In fact, for each $t\in\Bbb Q$ such that $f(t) = \lambda \in \Bbb Q\backslash \{0\}$, we have $0 = F(t) - \lambda G(t) = \sum_{i = 1}^n s_i \cdot (U_i(t) - \lambda V_i(t))$.
>
> Since the $s_i$'s are linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$, we have $U_i(t) = \lambda V_i(t)$. Thus for any $i, j$, we have $U_i(t)V_j(t) = V_i(t)U_j(t)$, or $D_{ij}(t) = 0$.
>
> By assumption, there are infinitely such $t$ (since there are only finitely many $t$ with $f(t) = 0$). Therefore $D_{ij}$ must be zero.

Since the denominator $G(x)$ is nonzero, there is at least one $i$ such that $V_i \neq 0$. Thus we have $$f = \frac{\sum_{j = 1}^n s_j U_j}{\sum_{j = 1}^n s_j V_j} = \frac{\sum_{j = 1}^n s_j V_iU_j}{V_i\sum_{j = 1}^n s_j V_j} = \frac{\sum_{j = 1}^n s_j U_iV_j}{V_i\sum_{j = 1}^n s_j V_j} = \frac{U_i}{V_i} \in \Bbb Q(x). $$

Comment: Thank you.  I understand your solution and I'm sure you're right. pretty nice solution, indeed.